# How to eliminate duplicate data using if condition in django template?

Tags: python, html, django

Is it okay to use if condition in template or html to eliminate duplicate data?

Note: I have already distinct **cores** in my views but since i have 2 loops in  **1 < tr >** it duplicates some data.

this is my html

```
{% for core in cores %}
    {% for behavior in behaviors %}
        {% if core.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name == behavior.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name %}
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" colspan="4" class="tblcoretitle">{{core.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name}} 1</td>
                {% if core.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName == behavior.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName  %}
                    <td colspan="4" class="tblcore"> {{behavior.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName}}
                    </td>
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
                <td class="tblcore">1</td>
                <td class="tblcore">2</td>
                <td class="tblcore">3</td>
                <td class="tblcore">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {% if core.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName == behavior.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName  %}
                {% else %}
                    <td colspan="4" class="tblcore">{{behavior.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName}}
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

this is my views.py

```
cores = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher) \
        .filter(Students_Enrollment_Records__in=Students.values_list('id')).values('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name','Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName').distinct('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name')\
    .order_by('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name')


behaviors = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher) \
        .filter(Students_Enrollment_Records__in=Students.values_list('id')).filter().values('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name','Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName').distinct('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName')\
    .order_by('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName')
```

this is my current result

[image]

this is i want result

[image]

mate if you have a better solution or idea please share your answer.

**UPDATE**

when i tried this in views,

```
cores = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher) \
        .filter(Students_Enrollment_Records__in=Students.values_list('id')).values(
        'Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name', 'Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName').distinct(
        'Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name') \
        .order_by('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name')

    behaviors = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher) \
        .filter(Students_Enrollment_Records__in=Students.values_list('id')).values(
        'Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name', 'Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName').distinct(
        'Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName') \
        .order_by('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName')

    matches = cores.union(behaviors)
```

my html

```
    {% for match in matches %}
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="4" class="tblcoretitle">{{match.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name}} 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="tblcore">{{match.Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName}}</td>
            <td class="tblcore">1</td>
            <td class="tblcore">2</td>
            <td class="tblcore">3</td>
            <td class="tblcore">4</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

this is the result:

[image]

**it duplicate the Core values**

Were about to solve this mate, a little more adjustment. thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** again

when i use

```
matches = itertools.chain(cores, behaviors)
```

the result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using two filterings in the same object, why not merge them in order to avoid duplication and using two for-loop in your template.

```
import itertools

cores = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher) \
            .filter(Students_Enrollment_Records__in=Students.values_list('id')).values('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name','Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName').distinct('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name')\
        .order_by('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name')


behaviors = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher) \
            .filter(Students_Enrollment_Records__in=Students.values_list('id')).values('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__Name','Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName').distinct('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName')\
        .order_by('Grading_Behavior__Grading_Behavior__GroupName')

matches = itertools.chain(cores, behaviors)
```

Comment: Interesting, but how i call it in html?

Comment: I receive this error AssertionError: Cannot combine queries with different distinct fields.

Comment: mate, how do i call it in my html?

Comment: A single for : `{% for match in matches %}{%endfor%}`. You can drop conditions

Comment: mate please check my update question, in order for you to see the result

Comment: do not use `union` use instead `itertools.chain`. Updated my answer

Comment: hmm, I see. Let's try: `matches = set(cores.union(behaviors))`. The set will remove duplicates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210164/discussion-between-justin-and-wariored).

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' i receive this error